# C-Style i++ for is deprecated in swift issue

Tags: swift

I want to increment **index** at some point for this loop it prints 1,3,5 which is i want to. I get the warning

### C-Style for statement is deprecated and ...

i know what it means.

```
for var index=0; index<5; index++ {
    //If condition A == true
    index++
    //else without index++
    print(index) // print 1, 3, 5
}
```

So i changed it to:

```
for var index in 0..<5 {
    //If condition A == true
    index += 1
    //else without index++
    print(index) // print 1,2,3,4,5 Should 1,3,5 from my side
}
```

I just wondering why index not mutable? Even though i have set it to `var` or any solutions for my issue.

Comment: See my edit, the prints not correct.

Comment: For second loop should print out 1,3,5 from my side.

Comment: try using Stride option. it's shown other places on stackoverfow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is not mutable because

```
for var x in y { 
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for temp in y { 
    var x = temp
    ...
}
```

where the var just makes `x` a copy of `temp`. When you modify `x`, it won't modify the real index `temp` (This is also a reason why [SE-0003](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md) is introduced)

---

The C-style `for` loop can just be reduced to a `while` loop:

```
var index = 0
while index < 5 {
    if conditionA {
        index += 1
    }
    print(index)
    index += 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to enumerate odd numbers, the simplest way will be to use `stride`:

```
for i in 1.stride(through: 5, by: 2) {
    print(i) // prints 1, 3, 5
}
```

Comment: No, i want control the loop times by condition, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "control the loop times by condition"?

Comment: if condition A is true the loop might be 5 times, else 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe swift loop variables are immutable when using the for in loop. Mutating a loop variable inside the loop is usually (one could argue always) a bad idea so it makes sense the swift designers didn't allow it. The desired result can be accomplished in cleaner ways, for instance using `continue`.

```
for i in 1...5
{
    if i%2==0
    {
        continue
    }
    print(i) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the results you want:

```
for var index in 0..<3 {
    print(2 * index + 1)
}
```

Comment: I need index to control the loop times too.